# How to make Traefik compatible with Microk8s

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, traefik, minikube, microk8s

I have a working setup on Minikube with Traefik as ingress controller. I tried to use that setup on Microk8s but Traefik is not able to work and although I can see the Traefik dashboard and it says that everything is working but every time I try to use the ingress urls I face timeout but if I use the endpoint IP of that service (which I can see in the traefik dashboard) I am able to access to that service but not fully. I can have access to `IP/service1` but I can't have access to any of its sub urls, `IP/service1/sub-service1` not working.

I also tried `microk8s.enable ingress` but it created an nginx ingress for me and then I disabled it because I want to use traefik.

Do I need to change my configuration so it becomes compatible with Microk8s? If yes how?

I have to mention that I have two ingress files:

- `traefik-ui.yaml`: which contains both the service and ingress for my traefik. I use this service+ingress to access the traefik dashboard and as I mentioned it works
- `wws-ingress.yaml`: is my main ingress which enables the communication with my components inside kubernetes and this is the part that doesn't work.

My yaml files:

traefik-ui.yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  rules:
  - host: traefik-ui.minikube
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: traefik-web-ui
          servicePort: web
```

wws-ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wws
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
    traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefixStrip
    traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: "true"
    traefik.backend.loadbalancer.sticky: "true"
    #traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: ReplacePathRegex
    traefik.wss.protocol: http
    traefik.wss.protocol: https
spec:
  rules:
  - host: streambridge.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /streambridge
        backend:
          serviceName: streambridge
          servicePort: 9999
      - path: /dashboard
        backend:
          serviceName: dashboard
          servicePort: 9009
      - path: /gateway
        backend:
          serviceName: gateway
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /rdb
        backend:
          serviceName: rethinkdb
          servicePort: 8085
```

Minikube commands (this works without a problem):

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/v1.7/examples/k8s/traefik-rbac.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/v1.7/examples/k8s/traefik-ds.yaml

kubectl apply -f traefik-ui.yaml
kubectl apply -f wws-ingress.yaml
```

And in Microk8s I tried:

```
microk8s.kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/v1.7/examples/k8s/traefik-rbac.yaml
microk8s.kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/v1.7/examples/k8s/traefik-ds.yaml
microk8s.kubectl apply -f traefik-ui.yaml
microk8s.kubectl apply -f wws-ingress.yaml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing my setup on another machine and seeing that it is working there I found out that something is wrong with my machine and after spending a good amount of time on this with the help of two of my colleagues and trying everything we found out that the problem is related to iptable in my machine and we solved it as described here: https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/72